# vue 3 wrap conditionally parent component, keep the child component

Tags: vue.js, conditional-statements, vue-component, vuejs3

I want to wrap the parent component conditionally without affecting the chikd component. Please check below example of what exactly I want in vue 3

```html
<template>
  <el-col v-if="column.length> 0" :xs="column.xs" :sm="column.sm" :lg="column.lg" :xl="column.xl">
  <el-form-item
    :prop="formItems.prop"
    :label="formItems.label"
  >
    <el-input
      v-model="props.modelValue"
      @input="$emit('update', $event)"
      :placeholder="props.placeholder"
      :type="props.type"
      :autocomplete="props.autocomplete"
      :suffix-icon="props.icon"
    />
  </el-form-item>
</el-col>
</template>
```

Here I want to wrap `<el-col>` component with specific condition. I have used the v-if but not work as I need to show the child element as it is just want to wrap parent component `<el-col>` conditionally.

> Working code but returning warning `[Vue warn] Set operation on key "modelValue" failed: target is readonly.` on typing

**Parent component**

```html
<template>
  <InputColumn
    :column="{ xs: 24, sm: 12, lg: 8, xl: 6 }"
    :formItems="{
      label: 'Prefix',
      prop: 'prefix',
      rules: [
        {
          required: true,
          message: 'Enter value',
          trigger: 'change',
        },
      ],
    }"
    v-model="prefix"
    placeholder="Prefix"
    @update="(v) => (prefix = v)"
  />
</template>
```

**Child component**

```html
<template>
  <el-col :xs="column.xs" :sm="column.sm" :lg="column.lg" :xl="column.xl">
    <el-form-item
      :prop="formItems.prop"
      :label="formItems.label"
      :rules="formItems.rules"
    >
      <el-input
        v-model="props.modelValue"
        @input="$emit('update:modelValue', $event)"
        :placeholder="props.placeholder"
        :type="props.type"
        :autocomplete="props.autocomplete"
        :suffix-icon="props.icon"
      />
    </el-form-item>
  </el-col>
</template>
<script setup>
defineEmits(["update:modelValue"]);
const props = defineProps({
  modelValue: {
    type: [String, Number],
    required: true,
    default: "",
  },
  type: {
    type: String,
    required: false,
    default: "",
  },
  placeholder: {
    type: String,
    required: false,
    default: "",
  },
  autocomplete: {
    type: String,
    required: false,
    default: "off",
  },
  icon: {
    type: String,
    required: false,
    default: "",
  },
  formItems: {
    type: Object,
    required: false,
  },
  column: {
    type: Object,
    required: false,
    default: { xs: 24, sm: 24, lg: 8, xl: 8 },
  },
});
</script>
```

Comment: Do you mean that you only want to hide/show the parent and leave child always show?

Comment: @NehaSoni Yes but not hide/show. I want to be similar to v-if but only on parent and leave child always show.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you will apply a condition on the parent element, it will affect its child elements as well.

It's better to move your child elements into any component, and use it like this-

```
<template>
  <!-- If condition true, wrap child elements inside parent -->
  <el-col 
    v-if="column.length> 0" 
    :xs="column.xs" 
    :sm="column.sm" 
    :lg="column.lg" 
    :xl="column.xl"
  >
    <child-elements/>
  </el-col>

  <!-- Else show child elements without wrapped -->
  <child-elements v-else/>
</template>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I thought to do that but feel bad to repeat the code as in my case there are two other child components `<el-form-item>` `<el-input>` inside the parent component `<el-col>`. Is this best practice to do as per your way?

Comment: No, the code won't repeat. Moving the child elements to a separate component is a way to write the child elements' code only once. Now, as per the condition, the child component will only be mounted once, either inside the parent or without the parent.

Comment: Neha I am emitting the input value child to parent so if I create `el-input` in another component then maybe I need to emit el-input components to the el-col component and el-col component to the main component to get input value on change so still, need your help to indicate this is best practice or not to emit input event to two parent component.

Comment: It is a regular practice to pass data between child and parent by emitting events. So, I don't find any issue with this. However, you should use (two-way binding to pass data to a custom component)[https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/vuejs-add-v-model-support].

Comment: Thanks. I will try it but your provided link goes to 404. Can you please correct this?

Comment: Vue Docs: https://vuejs.org/guide/components/events.html#usage-with-v-model

Comment: Thank you for your comments. I have one confusion that do we need to write `@update:modelValue="newValue => searchText = newValue"` in a component? because I have not written this in my component on nuxt 3 just emits an event from the child component and in the parent just added the `v-model` and its working fine but on typing it returns the vue warning 
`[Vue warn] Set operation on key "modelValue" failed: target is readonly` Please help me to fix this warning

Comment: From the child, emit event like, `$emit('input', <any_value>)` and in parent listen like this, `@input="anyMethod"`, and use `anyMethod` like this, `anyMethod($event) { // }`

Comment: @NehaSoni I just tried and it working fine too but on typing, it returns the same vue warning

`[Vue warn] Set operation on key "modelValue" failed: target is readonly.`

Comment: Can you tell me how your input is looking like?

Comment: @NehaSoni I just edited the main question and added my till now parent and child component. Hope it will clear you more and please let me know if you need anything else. Also just for your note, I am using the `el-input` from element plus UI on child component

Comment: As far as I checked, seem some syntax mistakes, when you are using `v-model` on the parent then you need to use `:value` on the child side but you are using `v-model`. Try this at your child component- `<el-input  :value="props.modelValue" @input="$emit('update:modelValue', $event)"></el-input>`

Comment: @NehaSoni I tried this but as I said I am using the element plus component so on el-input we must need to pass `v-model` `:value` will not work. Please let me know if you have still any confusion about this.

Comment: @NehaSoni The vue warning that I mentioned is now removed. I just changed `v-model="props.modelValue"` to `:model-value="props.modelValue"` on my child component.

Thank you very much for answering and for your valuable time on this issue!

Comment: Okay, I am glad that the discussion is worthwhile. If your main problem "wrapping parent but leaving the child as is" is resolved by the above answer then you can mark it as accepted or upvote if you find it useful.